# get string from file path not in a path format

Tags: c#, filepath, streamwriter

I am getting file path of the StreamWriter

```
string fullPath = ((FileStream) (writer.BaseStream)).Name
```

which gives me:

```
C:\\P4\\depot\\projects\\_Delegates.generated.cs
```

Is there chance to get/convert this path to

```
C:\P4\depot\projects\_Delegates.generated.cs
```

without `\\` but only with `\` in a path.

Thanks

Comment: When you say that's what it gives you, do you actually mean that's what it looks like in the debugger?

Comment: Are you checking this in the debugger or is it the writing of `fullPath` (e.g. Console.WriteLine)? This seems like you're looking at it via the debugger which means that this is expected behaviour. The `fullPath` variable itself will have one slash as expected but the debugger escapes the string internally which is why you're seeing a double slash. Your code looks fine and seems to be working as it should, assuming you're noticing the double slash in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fullpath = fullpath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Basically, replace every double back-slash in the string with a single slash.

Comment: 99.9% wrong answer - OP looks at the string in debugger and it gives him view with `\\` (escaped back slash). Nothing wrong with value.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't know that, how was I expected to do so? I thought that it was odd, but I posted it anyways, as it might actually be some obscure bug with some class library he's using.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, it is not problem with your answer - just after seeing the same problem 100 times you'll know what exactly is happening. (Also one could guess it because `File`/`Stream` APIs never return such confusing results). And I should not have said "wrong", more like "unlikely helpful" - sorry about that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've never seen this problem before, that's why I posted this answer. I'll be aware of it for the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\\P4\\depot\\projects\\_Delegates.generated.cs
```

--That should be what the actual string literal is, because the extra backslashes are needed as escape sequences.  So in other words, if you were going to define the path yourself by just making a string variable, you would type it in that form...

```
string fullpath = "C:\\P4\\depot\\projects\\_Delegates.generated.cs"
```

But, if you were to actually print out the value with `Console.WriteLine(fullpath);` The value you would actually see printed out would be:

```
C:\\P4\\depot\\projects\\_Delegates.generated.cs
```

In other words, its basically already in the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Regex Replace function from Regular Expression

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
private string Inhalt1 = null;
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(WindowsPath);

Regex rgx= new Regex(@"\\s");
NewPath= rgx.Replace(file, "\");   // the new Path
```